# How to get inline attachments (inline images) only?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph.

How to get inline attachments (inline images) only?

I tried both v1.0 and beta API

```
GET /me/messages/{messageId}/attachments?$filter=isInline eq true
```

But it always gives me all attachments including attachments that `isInline` is false.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828044/cannot-use-filter-on-attachments-query