# Cannot use filter on attachments query?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Learning from here: [List attachments](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_list_attachments) and [Use query parameters](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter)

When I call `v1.0/me/messages/{message id}/attachments/?$filter=isInline eq true`.
It returns both inline and not inline.

When I call `v1.0/me/messages/{message id}/attachments/?$filter=size gt 15000`.
It returns attachments with all sizes, included for example 14000.

It just ignores the filter parameter...

Is this correct? Documentation says nothing about that.

Is there another way to get only the inline attachments with one query?

Answer (score 3):

There is a known bug with the `/attachments` endpoint affecting support the `$filter` clause.

You can track the [status of this issue at GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1974). I've also added a reference to your question here.